# mysql stored procedure updates all rows instead of 1

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Here is the **MySQL** procedure:

```
    CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%` PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN comp_id VARCHAR(40))
    BEGIN
    ...
    UPDATE tbl_complaint SET DIDM_Docket_No = '2013-12-12' WHERE Comp_ID = comp_id;
    END;
```

This is how it looks when i call the procedure:

```
    call gen_docketno('{74651651-9D76-C973-175A-97B9B78608A5}')
```

Is it because of **the brackets and dash** in value of the parameter that the procedure can't update properly? because when i run this in sql query it works but not when in stored procedure.

```
    UPDATE tbl_complaint SET DIDM_Docket_No = '2013-12-12' WHERE Comp_ID = '{BF16E293-6CD2-8BC3-91B1-CF5AC70A090B}';
```

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: `WHERE Comp_ID = comp_id` = update all!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Over Flow! `:D`

Answer (score 7):

rename your parameter `comp_id`. it collides with your column name causing it to update all records,

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN _comp_id VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
...
     UPDATE tbl_complaint 
     SET DIDM_Docket_No = '2013-12-12' 
     WHERE Comp_ID = _comp_id;
END;
```